# Is there a way to get typed dependencies using OpenNlp?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I am trying to extract the subject, object and predicate triplets of a sentence. I am required to use the typed dependencies in order to find out the relationship between the triplets. I am using OpenNlp to do this. I know Stanford Nlp provides typed dependency parser but I would like to do it with OpenNlp